# Trying to extend code to carry on through program

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the program to carry on through the program, however, there is an error, please see below:

[image]

It seems the input is wrong when I enter options 4 and 5. I was hoping you could please review my code and see if you find anything sinister.

Yet, there is more code to be executed (see attached code) for the `Main` class:

```java
System.out.println("1.JOB SEEKER\n2.JOB PROVIDER\nENTER YOUR CHOICE");
choice=obj.nextInt();
if(choice==1)
{
    while(true)
    {
        while(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("\n   Menu");
            System.out.println("1. ADD YOUR RESUME");
            System.out.println("2.TO SEARCH AND GENERATE PRINT OUT OF YOUR RESUME ");
            System.out.println("3.TO UPDATE YOU DETAILS ");
            System.out.println("4.TO SHOW ALL JOBS \n5.TO SHOW BEST JOB\n6.QUIT");
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = obj.nextInt();
            switch (choice) {
                case 1:
                    FileWriter fout = new FileWriter("job2.txt", true);
                    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                        System.out.print("enter phno: ");
                        record2.phno = obj.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("Enter name:");
                        record2.name = obj.next();
                        System.out.print("Enter degree:");
                        record2.deg = obj.next();
                        System.out.println("Enter your percentage");
                        record2.eduper=obj.nextInt();
                        System.out.print("Enter  place:");
                        record2.add = obj.next();
                        System.out.println("enter sal");
                        record2.expsal = obj.nextInt();
                        fout.write(record2.phno + "           \n");
                        fout.write(record2.name + "         \n");
                        fout.write(record2.deg + "              \n");
                        fout.write(record2.eduper + "           \n");
                        fout.write(record2.add + "                \n");
                        fout.write(record2.expsal + "          \n");
                    }
                    fout.write("\r\012");
                    fout.close();
                    System.out.println("File is created");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i=0;
                    System.out.print("enter phno: ");
                    double phno = obj.nextInt();
                    FileReader fin = new FileReader("job2.txt");
                    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fin);
                    while (sc.hasNextFloat()) {
                        record2.phno = sc.nextInt();
                        record2.name = sc.next();
                        record2.deg = sc.next();
                        record2.eduper=sc.nextInt();
                        record2.add = sc.next();
                        record2.expsal = sc.nextInt();
                        if (phno == record2.phno) {
                            i++;
                            System.out.println(+i);
                            record2.displayRecord();
                        }
                    }
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("no resume found ");
                        break;
                        //fin.close();
                    }
                    fin.close();
                    int k1=0;
                    FileReader fin34 = new FileReader("job2.txt");
                    Scanner sc3 = new Scanner(fin34);
                    while (sc3.hasNextInt()) {
                        record2.phno = sc3.nextInt();
                        record2.name = sc3.next();
                        record2.deg = sc3.next();
                        record2.eduper=sc3.nextInt();
                        record2.add = sc3.next();
                        record2.expsal = sc3.nextInt();
                        if (phno == record2.phno) {
                            k1++;
                            if(i==k1)
                            {
                                //  System.out.println(+k);
                                record2.displayRecord();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    i=0;
                    System.out.print("enter phno: ");
                    phno = obj.nextDouble();
                    FileReader fin1 = new FileReader("job2.txt");
                    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(fin1);
                    while (sc1.hasNextFloat()) {
                        record2.phno = sc1.nextInt();
                        record2.name = sc1.next();
                        record2.deg = sc1.next();
                        record2.eduper=sc1.nextInt();
                        record2.add = sc1.next();
                        record2.expsal = sc1.nextInt();
                        if(phno==record2.phno)
                        {
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(i==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("no resume found ");
                        break;
                        //fin.close();
                    }
                    k1=0;
                    FileReader fin4 = new FileReader("job2.txt");
                    Scanner sc4 = new Scanner(fin4);
                    while (sc4.hasNextFloat()) {
                        record2.phno = sc4.nextInt();
                        record2.name = sc4.next();
                        record2.deg = sc4.next();
                        record2.eduper=sc4.nextInt();
                        record2.add = sc4.next();
                        record2.expsal = sc4.nextInt();
                        if (phno == record2.phno) {
                            k1++;
                            if(i==k1)
                            {
                                record2.displayRecord();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("press 1 to continue else 0");
                    choice=obj.nextInt();
                    if(choice==1)
                    {
                        FileWriter fout1 = new FileWriter("job2.txt", true);
                        for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                            System.out.print("Enter name:");
                            record2.name = obj.next();
                            System.out.print("Enter degree:");
                            record2.deg = obj.next();
                            System.out.println("Enter your percentage");
                            record2.eduper=obj.nextInt();
                            System.out.print("Enter  place:");
                            record2.add = obj.next();
                            System.out.println("enter sal");
                            record2.expsal = obj.nextInt();
                            fout1.write(record2.phno + "           \n");
                            fout1.write(record2.name + "         \n");
                            fout1.write(record2.deg + "              \n");
                            fout1.write(record2.eduper + "              \n");
                            fout1.write(record2.add + "                \n");
                            fout1.write(record2.expsal + "          \n");
                        }
                        fout1.write("\r\012");
                        fout1.close();
                        System.out.println("YOUR RESUME IS UPDATED");
                        fin1.close();
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("enter degree ");
                    String cname1 = obj.next();
                    FileReader fin11 = new FileReader("job3.txt");
                    Scanner sc11 = new Scanner(fin11);
                    while(sc11.hasNextFloat())
                    {
                        record1.phno = sc11.nextDouble();
                        record1.cname = sc11.next();
                        record1.degreq= sc11.next();
                        record1.reqper=sc11.nextInt();
                        record1.add=sc11.next();
                        record1.sal=sc11.nextInt();
                        if(cname1.equals(record1.degreq))
                        {
                            record1.displayRecord();
                            phno3++;
                        }
                    }
                    fin11.close();
                    if(phno3==0)
                    {
                        System.out.println("no job found");
                    }
```

Comment: After calling method `nextInt()` and before calling method `next()`, you need to call method `nextLine()`. Refer to [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information. Exception stacktrace should be posted as code-formatted text.